# Verifying an analytical solution to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble in verifying that $y=\frac{4}{\exp(t)+\exp(-t)}$ is an analytical solution to $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}=-\sqrt{y^2-\frac{y^4}{4}}$, where the initial condition is $y(0)=2$.

I have tried with help of substitution, where i end up with the following;

$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}+\sqrt{y^2-\frac{y^4}{4}} = -\frac{4(\exp(t)-\exp(-t))}{(\exp(t)+\exp(-t))^2}+\sqrt\frac{16(\exp(t)+\exp(t))-64}{(\exp(t)+\exp(-t))^4}$

With the $-64$ inside the sqrt, I can not see you this can result in $0$.

Comment: Yes, i know. But I dont get it to show that $y'(t) + \sqrt{(y^2-\frac{y^4}{4})}=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y = 2 \sech t$

$y' =$$-2 \sech t \tanh t\\- y (\sqrt {1+\sech^2 t}\\ -y\sqrt {1+\frac {y^2}{4}}\\-\sqrt{y^2 - \frac{y^4}{4}}$

I guess that Mathjax doesn't recognize the hyperbolic secant function.

Comment: we can use $y = 2 \sec_h t$ for tiime being?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that $y\equiv 0$ is a solution, this IVP has an always positive solution. To reduce the degree you can borrow an idea from Bernoulli equations and substitute $y=\frac2u$, $u(0)=1$,
$$
-\frac{2u'}{u^2}=y'=-\sqrt{\frac{4}{u^2}-\frac{4}{u^4}}
\\
\iff
\\
u'=\sqrt{u^2-1}
$$
which now integrates per separation as $\text{Arcosh}(u)=t+c$.